# Python GUI Events

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm sure this question has been asked many times before, so I apologize in advance. I simply cannot find the answer via google or searching stack overflow.

I'm working in python with the wx library. I simply need a `wx.EVT_CHAR` to be thrown anytime a user presses a key, no matter the focus. How can this be accomplished? Is there a way to bind all widgets? Or a way to always throw an event when application receives a key press?

I tried binding the application itself, the main frame, and the main panel. None of these have accomplished the job of always throwing a `wx.EVT_CHAR` when a key is pressed.

Comment: afaik you cant really accomplish this with wx (And I have yet to see a good solution) ... they have to have focus on an object that has user focus ... you might be able use something like `windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo`

Comment: ... or maybe `win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by writing a recursive method that sets every widget to receive characters and binds every widget to my callback function. It's pretty simple, but took me a bit of googling to realize that not every widget can inherently receive text events (such as a button). Hopefully this will save someone some time in the future. It should be noted that only widgets that are children or subchildren of the parent window passed will be bound to the callback method.

```
def __RecursiveBinding(self, parent):
    try:
        parent.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.CharInputCallback)
        parent.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.WANTS_CHARS)
        parent.Refresh()

        children = parent.GetChildren()

        if(children):
            for child in children:
                self.__RecursiveBinding(child)
```